# Android development Linking XML button to Java

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android development, I am basically trying to create a very basic app which will enable the user to switch on their wifi.

My XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:text="@string/welcome"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/wifi_on"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    android:text="@string/wifi_button" />
```

`

My Java file:

`package com.example.dosomething;`

`import android.os.Bundle;`
`import android.app.Activity;`
`import android.view.Menu;`
`import android.view.View;`
`import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`
`import android.widget.Button;`

`public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {`

```
protected Button wifi_on;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}

public Button getWifiOn(){


    return wifi_on;

} 


public void setWifiOn(Button on){

    wifi_on = on;


}
```

}`

My question is how can I refer to the button inside the XML file onto the java file to further tell it that if the button is clicked on it should turn on the wifi. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this.

1. What you can do is add this line to your `<Button` tag in xml

   `android:onClick="setWifiOn"`

then change the parameter of that function to

```
public void getWifiOn(View v){


return wifi_on;

}
```

with this you don't need the `onClick` or any listeners

2.You can do something similar if you want all `Buttons` to share the same function then give them all the function name like

```
android:onClick="someFunction"
```

then in Java do something like

```
public void someFunction(View v)
{
    Button btn = (Button)v;  
    switch (v.getId())
    {
       case (R.id.wifi_on:
        setWifiOn(btn);
        break;
       case (R.id.differentBtnId):
       // do some other things
       break;
     }
}

}
```

3.Less attractive in many situations, IMHO

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button wifiBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wifi_on);
    wifiBtn.setOnClickListener(this);  // your onClick below will be called then you will still have to check the id of the Button
    // multiple buttons can set the same listener and use a switch like above

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

**Note** number 3 is the only one in which you need `implements OnClickListener`

[Button Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

I left out the other way because I think its the ugliest if you have more than one `Button`