# How do I show complete calculation in textview?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview

How do I show complete calculation in textview using parenthesis? For example: 2+3-((4/2)*9)
            I am making calculator app which uses parenthesis and remember calculations history and should display all math operation in textview.

Here is my code:

```
    package com.example.calculater;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener { 
        TextView textdisplay;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            textdisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
            Button b1 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            Button b2 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
            Button b3 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
            Button b4 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
            Button b5 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
            Button b6 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
            Button b7 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
            Button b8 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8);
            Button b9 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9);
            Button b0 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn0);
            Button multiply1 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
            Button divide1 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);
            Button plus1 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
            Button minus1 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
            Button equal1 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.equal);
            Button clear1 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
            Button back1 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.backspace);
            Button dot1 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.decimal);
            Button plusminus1 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.plusminus);
            Button history1=  (Button) findViewById(R.id.history);
            Button open1 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.open);
            Button close1 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.close);

            b1.setOnClickListener(this);
            b2.setOnClickListener(this);
            b3.setOnClickListener(this);
            b4.setOnClickListener(this);
            b5.setOnClickListener(this);
            b6.setOnClickListener(this);
            b7.setOnClickListener(this);
            b8.setOnClickListener(this);
            b9.setOnClickListener(this);
            b0.setOnClickListener(this);
            multiply1.setOnClickListener(this);
            divide1.setOnClickListener(this);
            plus1.setOnClickListener(this);
            minus1.setOnClickListener(this);
            equal1.setOnClickListener(this);
            clear1.setOnClickListener(this);
            back1.setOnClickListener(this);
            dot1.setOnClickListener(this);
            plusminus1.setOnClickListener(this);
            history1.setOnClickListener(this);
            open1.setOnClickListener(this);
            close1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        int clear_flag = 0;
        String sign_flag = "";
        Double total = 0.0;
        int last_button = 0;

        public void shownum (String number){
            if(clear_flag==1){
                textdisplay.setText("");
                clear_flag=0;
            }
            else if(textdisplay.getText()=="0"){
                textdisplay.setText("");
            }
            textdisplay.setText(textdisplay.getText() + number);
        }


        public void showsign(String sign){
            if(last_button==R.id.plus || last_button==R.id.minus || last_button==R.id.multiply 
            || last_button==R.id.divide){

            }
            else{
                clear_flag = 1;//set flag
                Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(textdisplay.getText().toString());
                if(sign_flag == "" || sign_flag == "="){
                    total = newNumber;
                    textdisplay.setText(total.toString());  
                }
                else if(sign_flag == "+"){
                    total = total + newNumber;
                    textdisplay.setText(total.toString());

                }
                else if(sign_flag == "-"){
                    total = total - newNumber;
                    textdisplay.setText(total.toString());
                }
                else if(sign_flag == "*"){
                    total = total*newNumber;
                    textdisplay.setText(total.toString());
                }
                else if(sign_flag == "/"){
                    total = total/newNumber;
                    textdisplay.setText(total.toString());  
                }}
            sign_flag = sign;
            }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getId() == R.id.btn0){
                shownum ("0");
            }
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.btn1){
                shownum ("1");
            }
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.btn2){
                shownum ("2");
            }
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.btn3){
                shownum ("3");
            }
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.btn4){
                shownum ("4");
            }
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.btn5){
                shownum ("5");
            }
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.btn6){
                shownum ("6");
            }
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.btn7){
                shownum ("7");
            }
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.btn8){
                shownum ("8");
            }
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.btn9){
                shownum ("9");
            }
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.clear){
                textdisplay.setText("");////ORIGINALLY ITS WAS 0 ""
                total = 0.0;
                sign_flag = "";
            }
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.decimal){
                if(clear_flag==1){
                    textdisplay.setText("");
                    clear_flag = 0;
                }
                if(textdisplay.getText().toString().indexOf(".")<0){
                    textdisplay.setText(textdisplay.getText() + ".");
                    }}
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.backspace){
                if(textdisplay.getText().toString().length()>0){
                    int start = 0;
                    int end = textdisplay.getText().toString().length()-1;
                    String newText = textdisplay.getText().toString().substring(start,end);
                    textdisplay.setText(newText);
            }}
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.plus){
                showsign("+");

            }
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.minus){
                showsign("-");

            }
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.multiply){
                showsign("*");

            }
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.divide){
                showsign("/");

            }
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.equal){
                Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(textdisplay.getText().toString());
                if(sign_flag == "+"){
                    total = total+newNumber;
                    textdisplay.setText(total.toString());
                }
                else if(sign_flag == "-"){
                    total = total-newNumber;
                    textdisplay.setText(total.toString());
                }
                else if(sign_flag == "*"){
                    total = total*newNumber;
                    textdisplay.setText(total.toString());
                }
                else if(sign_flag == "/"){
                    total = total/newNumber;
                    textdisplay.setText(total.toString());
                }
                sign_flag = "=";
    }       //when minus is pressed before any number input, applications closes. 
                else if (v.getId() == R.id.plusminus){
                String number = textdisplay.getText().toString();
                if(number == null) return;  //exits function
                if(number.equals("")) return;  //exits function
               // textdisplay.setText("Please enter number first then press +/-");
                Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(number);
                total = newNumber * (-1);
                textdisplay.setText(total.toString());

                }

                else if (v.getId()== R.id.open){


                }
                else if (v.getId()== R.id.close){

                }

            last_button = v.getId();
    }}





Here is my XML code:




<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5pt"
        android:layout_weight="0.58"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/divide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="/" />




        <Button
            android:id="@+id/multiply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="*" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backspace"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1" 

            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plusminus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+/-" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/decimal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="." />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/open"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="( " />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=")" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.58" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.20" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.04"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/history"
                    android:layout_width="252dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="History" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/equal"
                    android:layout_width="248dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/_" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Store them in a variable and display the variable value? Also, `==` is the wrong way to compare `String`s. You want `.equals()`

Comment: It will work just not correctly. So display it. You haven't said what the actual problem is and that is too much code to sift through without knowing what your problem is. [Also, see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958552/android-development-linking-xml-button-to-java/17958602#17958602) on putting `onClick` in your xml. It will tidy up your code.

Comment: `but with == my app still works`  Only by accident and one day, it won't work (Google for string interning).  Just read the documentation - `equals()` is the method to use.  In Java, `String` is an object and not a primitive.  `==` therefore tests whether two objects are the same object.

Comment: Simon, Wht should i do to display my operations in textview? Pls help

Comment: codeMagic already gave you the answer.  Store each digit, operator and bracket in a single variable and display that.

Answer (score 0):

What codeMagic said, store each in a variable and then maybe make one `final String` variable to hold it with `String.format`. So maybe

```
String finalString = String.format("This is the result %s and %s" , 
        variableName, variableName);
```

then

```
textdisplay.setText(finalString);
```

Comment: Yes it works. How to use parenthesis in my calculations?

Comment: Try putting a backslash before the ( ...like String.format("This is the result \\(%s\\) and \\(%s\\) , variableName, variableName);