# How to fix some issues with Intent for open a new Window in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, class, android-intent, android-activity

I'm new in Android and I want to do a very easy app: I want click on a button and open a new window. I know that I have to use the Intent but I have some problems. Here my code.

first XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Password"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/UserName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/UserName"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/UserName"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        style="@style/TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="@string/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        style="@style/TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
        android:text="@string/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Create"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/Create" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Login"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Create"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Create"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="@string/Login" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

second XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context="com.example.prenotazione.Login$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Password"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/UserName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/UserName"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/UserName"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        style="@style/TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="@string/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        style="@style/TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
        android:text="@string/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        style="@style/TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/UserName"
        android:text="@string/TextView01" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Create02"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="@string/Create" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I show you my Java file:
first activity:

```
package com.example.prenotazione_esame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Button button_crea = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Create);
        button_crea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                openCreateAccount();
            }
        });
    }

   private void openCreateAccount(){
       Intent intent_crea = new Intent(this, CreateAccountActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent_crea);
   }
}
```

second activity:

```
package com.example.prenotazione_esame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CreateAccountActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.createaccount);
    }

}
```

and finally my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.prenotazione_esame"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.prenotazione_esame.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="CreateAccountActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>



    </application>

</manifest>`
```

the problem is in the first activity java file. When I do this line of code Intent intent_crea = new Intent(this, CreateAccountActivity.class); Eclipse send me an error: CreateAccountActivity cannot be resolve to a type. Where is the problem?? Thank you.

Comment: try doing android:name=".CreateAccountActivity". Don't think it will make a difference but it is how I have always done it :P

Comment: **Off-topic**: since you only create that `onClick()` to call a method, you can put `android:onClick="openCreateAccount"` and get rid of the `OnClickListener`. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958552/android-development-linking-xml-button-to-java/17958602#17958602)

Answer (score 0):

Dalvik (which is the Virtual Machine which is trying to instance your classes in Android) is relying on your manifest file to resolve to actual classes. To do this it uses the package and the class which should take it to your Activity's class.

The package is `package="com.example.prenotazione_esame"`. To have the file lead to the actual class you need to declare it as `.CreateAccountActivity` which, translated to Dalvik means `com.example.prenotazione_esame.CreateAccountActivity`.

You should change `com.example.prenotazione_esame.LoginActivity` to `.LoginActivity` in the same file as well, for the same reasons.