# Android: OnClickListener inside of a public void

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, buttonclick

```
public class Levels extends Activity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.levels);
    }

    public void A01(View view)
    {
        //code.....
    }
    public void A02(View view)
    {
        //code.....
    }
    public void A03(View view)
    {
        //code.....
    }


    //All the same.....

    public void A90(View view)
    {
        //code.....
    }

    public void listenlist(View view)
    {
         //????.....
    }
 }
```

above is a demo of my code, is there anyway i can use an OnClickerlistener INSIDE of listenlist()
i want them inside because of it being so messy when they are on the outside.

can i do anything like this?:

```
public void listenlist(View view)
{
    View.OnClickListener listener= new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            switch(view.getId())
            {
            case R.id.A01:
            // code.....
            break;
            case R.id.A02:
            // code.....
            break;
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: The best way to find out is to try it. Anyway, it would only get invoked when you call that method. So, if you aren't doing anything else inside of the method then just use that as your `onClick()`.[See here on how to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958552/android-development-linking-xml-button-to-java/17958602#17958602)

Comment: just give it a try man.

Comment: @codeMagic thanks, i got wat i wanted from ur link

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked for you.